# PHP not able to read $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to read $_FILES uploaded by my AJAX upload form. This is the POST request:

```
POST myhost.net/csv.php

Host: myhost.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: application%2Fjson%2C%20text%2Fjavascript%2C%20*%2F*%3B%20q%3D0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-File-Name: Europe_1351.csv
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Referer: http://myhost.net
Content-Length: 26
Cookie: PHPSESSID=kourjvs7rm980d2cg4qvaav965
Connection: keep-alive
```

And on the server side, I got:

```
var_dump( $_FILES );
```

Even though 'multipart/form-data' is set, there aren't any data in $_FILES variable. Does this have something to do with PHP configuration? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader/master/SimpleAjaxUploader.js">
      $(document).ready(function() 
      {
        var sizeBox = document.getElementById('sizeBox');

        var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
              button:               'uploadButton', // file upload button
              url:                  'csv.php', // server side handler
              name:                 'uploadfile', // upload parameter name        
              contentType:          'multipart/form-data',
              responseType:         'json',
              allowedExtensions:    ['csv'],
              maxSize:              10 * 1024, // kilobytes
              hoverClass:           'ui-state-hover',
              focusClass:           'ui-state-focus',
              disabledClass:        'ui-state-disabled',
              onSubmit: function(filename, extension) 
              {
                  this.setFileSizeBox(sizeBox); // designate this element as file size container
                },         
              onComplete: function(filename, response) 
              {
                  if (!response) {
                      alert(filename + 'upload failed');
                      return false;            
                  }

                  alert( 'file ' + response.data + ' uploaded successfully ');
                  // do something with response...
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>


        <div id='uploadButton'>
           CSV
        </div>

        <div id='sizeBox'>
          size
        </div>
```

Comment: Okay.. please put your code

Comment: I think the function is var_dump( $_FILES ) not dump( $_FILES );

Comment: @tiGer I had my own dump function, var_dump doesn't return anything ether

Comment: Actually it is not var_dump problem basically you are using some other class for the same. well there should be an parameter for type i.e POST or GET, but unable to see such parameter.

Comment: @innovativekundan I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer. The method is already set to POST if that's what your asking

Comment: Dear @user3578847 unable to see POST method in your JS code.

Comment: because the script is calling POST method by default, in my question I specified the RAW request that is being executed. In addition, GET request cannot contain 'contain-type' header as well as other headers that are only POST specific

Answer (score 0):

Use php inbuilt function print_r();

print_r($_FILES);

Comment: print_r doesn't return anything, nether does count( $_FILES );